# invoking a method in the same line where object is being created and not creating a reference variable referring the object to invoke

Tags: java

why is this valid ?
Invoking a method in the same line where object is being created and not separately creating a reference variable referring the object to invoke  the method.

```
class A {

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Hello Everyone");
    }
}

class B {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A().show();/* at this point how does compiler know which show() method
                 to  run as I have not created any reference variable
                 pointing  to the object of class A, it could have run
                    class B's show() or simply have given an error */
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Hello Everyone, this is java");
    }
}
```

Please help I have finals.

Comment: You did create an instance of class A when you called new.  You invoked its show() method.  I have no idea what you're thinking with the rest.  There's a hint of inheritance thinking, but no extends.

Comment: @duffymo-what i want to ask is that object is created at run time hence method is being invoked dynamically at run time but as i  dont have a reference of type A, then how is compiler determining that my method invocation is correct ??? please clarify-@ duffymo

Comment: When you find yourself in a hole, stop digging.  You do have an instance of A when you call new.  You invoke its show() method.  There is no reference pointing to that instance, so it goes out of scope when the method exits.  Your method is correct; your understanding of Java is not.

Comment: There's only `A.show` and `B.show`... What one do you expect `new A().show()` to call? It's definitely not going to call the method in `B`.

Comment: @ duffymo- i am not that well versed with java, but from what i understood that "new" operator creates an object at "runtime" with the help of a class constructor and then only returns the reference of that object for a reference variable to hold.

Comment: I can see that.  Everything you said is correct - except for that last part.  As you've proven to yourself, you don't have to assign an instance to a reference after you've created it.  Why don't you believe the JVM?

Comment: `new X()` creates a new instance of the `X` class. Whether or not someone wants to store that in a variable is their choice. It's not necessary.

Comment: @duffymo-what if i extend class B from class A, then what will happen at compile time ?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `new A()`, you get a new object of type `A`. That's how `new` is defined.

Because you told the compiler that you want a new object of type `A`, it already knows the type, even if you don't assign it to a variable.